# Confusion regarding Changing flux

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a confusion regarding where flux changes and where it is constant.

When a flat coil moves between two opposite poles of a magnet, parallel to their faces we say the flux is constant and no emf was induced. There is only emf when the coil enters the uniform magnetic field between the poles faces.

But
When a wire *sweeps* out a magnetic field we take that there was a change of flux and hence an emf equal to $Blv$ in the wire. However isnt the flux also constant in the wire as we can consider it just like the coil?

[image]

So what is the difference between these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moving wire situation in which $d\Phi/dt=Blv$, the wire is typically part of a larger closed loop of conducting material (a circuit). The change in flux is due to the changing area of this loop, which is immersed in a uniform magnetic field.

Here's a plagiarized image illustrating this:

[image]

Comment: Oh yes now it's clear. Here I was wondering which area is responsible for Flux in this case