# Must the rod be connected to a frame to experience induced EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

I have three scenarios:

1. The following setup will experience an induced EMF since the area covered increases with time. (Shaded in orange)

[image: rod moving through magnetic field with rectangular borders]

2. If instead of a wire/rod,we had a coil moving within the field, there would be no induced EMF for a constant magnetic flux density since area covered by coil is fixed and does not vary with time.[image: Square coil moving within magnetic field]
3. The question is if I have something similar to the first scenario (in that a rod is used) but without borders, such that entire rod lies within the field (like the second scenario), would I get an induced EMF? If yes, what would be the change in area?
   [image: rod moving through magnetic field ut without borders]

Comment: This question has been asked before, the answer is yes, you get an Emf because the coil cuts through field lines as it moves

Comment: [or this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/471069/can-f-qvb-be-applied-to-a-solenoid-and-a-parallel-moving-magnet) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178022/confusion-regarding-changing-flux?rq=1)

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller Following the answer in your first link, Im not sure how to interpret this line, "Now when your rod is rotating at different instance different field lines are crossing it, it's not the same field lines throughout." It makes sense, but doesn't seem to explain the second scenario, since flux lines passing through the moving coil would also be different?

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller to quote the answer in the third link, "wire is typically part of a larger closed loop of conducting material" , does this mean there has to be rectangular borders for the EMF to be induced? (It's just not drawn in the diagram for scenario three?)

Comment: Sorry I took so long to reply, was down with a cold. It does explain, because the flux lines would still be cut by motion. It is the flux cutting that isi mportant. I foudn best explanation was in Richard Feynman's Lectures on this topic. He is the only place where I found the cutting concept. For the last question, maybe for detecting the presence of EMf you need a circuit, but the EMF does exist. You can the faraday's law effect in moving rod by using basic F=qE + qvxB and some assumptions @Sophie Lee

Comment: Alrights, get well soon and thanks for.the reply! I will take a look at the Feynman's lectures when I have time

Comment: sure! Let me know if you had any more questions